# EF Core 5 - Backing field: specified field could not be found for property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to create a backing field that consists of a JSON string which is then accessed by a property of the model and converted to a JObject:

```
public class StaticTable
    {
        public int StaticTableId { get; set; }
        private string _staticData { get; set; }

        public JObject StaticData
        {
            get => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_staticData) ? "{}" : _staticData);
            set => _staticData = value.ToString();
        }

        public static void RunFluent(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            EntityTypeBuilder<StaticTable> entity = modelBuilder.Entity<StaticTable>();
            entity.Property(s => s.StaticData).HasField("_staticData");
        }
    }
```

When creating a migration, I receive the following error:
`System.InvalidOperationException: The specified field '_staticData' could not be found for property 'StaticTable.StaticData'.`

Note that `RunFluent` is executed in `DbContext.OnModelCreating`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a private variable instead of a property

```
private string _staticData;
```